# Align text within a trapezoid

Tags: html, css

I created a right trapezoid using CSS where I am adding some text. My issue is that I cannot vertically align the text within the div. My steps are shown at the bottom of the question. Firstly, my code is shown below:

HTML:

```
<div class="headersection">
    <div class="logosection">TEXTtext</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}

.headersection {
    background-color:#222939;
    width:100%;
    height:75px;
    line-height:0;
    z-index:1;
    color:white;
}

.logosection {
    width:120px;
    border-bottom: 75px solid #ff0000;
    border-right: 75px solid transparent;
}
```

Secondly, using the code above I am getting this result where you can see the text is not aligned:

[image]

I tried adding the `display: table;` in the CSS for the `.headersection` and then I added this :

```
     display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
```

in the `.logosection`

Also, I tried adding this :

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center; 
align-items: center;
```

in the `.logosection`

and it is aligned horizontally but not vertically :

[image]

Comment: You apply the flex box styles in the container which in your case is `.headersection`. Do you have a jsfiddle or something else that would be useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) and set it be the height of the div:

```
.logosection {
    line-height: 75px;
    width:120px;
    border-bottom: 75px solid #ff0000;
    border-right: 75px solid transparent;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0q831mq1/

There is another technique using transform:

```css
div.parent {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 150px;
}

div.vertical {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="vertical">Vertical aligned text!</div>
</div>
```

<sup>This code sample based on SO Documentation example "Vertical align anything with 3 lines of code" (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170301083610/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/299/centering/7622/vertical-align-anything-with-3-lines-of-code#t=2017030108360977557).) ©2016 by [Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410735/someone) licensed under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).</sup>

Comment: I tried line-height but you also added display: flex in the .headersection and it works! Cheers